# Conversion of .m files to .mat

Tags: matlab

How do I convert a `.m` file to a `.mat` file that can be use as an argument for a function on MATLAB? The `.m` file is a matrix.

Comment: As this is a non-standard usage of m-files, can you post the beginning of your m-file ? Everything before the array definition and the beginning of the array definition, please.

Comment: 1) How does your m-file look like? Please provide an example. 2) How should your mat-file look like? For what function do you want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "The `.m` file is a matrix" but if it's already in the Matlab data format, can't you just change the extension directly?

If it's in any other format that you are able to import into the workspace, you can import it then use

```
save mydata.mat
```

to save it to a .mat file. Note that this will save all your workspace variables to the .mat file. To save only a specific variable, you can use the full form

```
save('mydata.mat', myVar)
```

You can also specify a relative or absolute path for the output file.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Say I have a file `loadcolor.m` and it contains a matrix of dimensions 10000x5 and I need to extract this into a `.mat` file which subsequently acts as input to other functions, will this work? I tried it but it did not work-I probably did something wrong.

Comment: As others have pointed out, I think it would be best if you could provide a sample of that file, or explain how you obtained it, because it's difficult to give an answer as it stands...

Comment: @S_SDhar loadcolor.m can not be a matrix. It can be a matlab code that only creates a matrix.

Comment: @S_SDhar I think you have misunderstood the difference between an `.m` file and a `.mat` file.